# How best to regularly update a PostgreSQL table which will only ever need to have 16 rows of data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm new to database stuff and am now using a cloud PostgreSQL db to store data from my Python web scraper. So far, so good.

My plan is the PostgreSQL db will only ever have 16 rows of data (one for each website I'm scraping) in its current iteration and they'll all be updated every 5 minutes (after the latest scrape) to have the freshest information.

I was converting a list of dictionaries to json and serving on a Flask API endpoint, but I want to separate the scraping and the endpoint and use a db instead.

Having read a bit the last day or two on this, I plan to drop the table and then create new table and insert the 16 fresh rows of data every 5 minutes, rather than keep all the old rows.

Would this have any downtime issues (with only 16 rows being inserted after drop table, I am hoping not). Also, is this advisable or is there a nicer way to do this?

I will have a React FE feeding off an endpoint which grabs the data from this database.

I'm curious as to how experienced devs would do this, is all. No emergency.

Comment: Dropping the table and recreating it every 5 minutes? You should use a excel sheet etc. not a database.

Comment: how easy to make an endpoint from an excel sheet etc

Comment: no, that is a bad idea, truncating maybe, but 16 weburls as primary key and update the rows inly if the hash of the site changes

Comment: that sounds better. not all will need updating every 5 mins. some might stay unchanged for an hour.

Comment: Not seeing why you want to crank up Postgres for just 16 rows of data. Seems one of the many key/values stores out there would be less overhead. Or if you are really wanting a database then [Sqlite](https://sqlite.org/index.html), which would be a much lighter option.